# How can I convert the first page of a PDF to a JPG using the NodeJS imagemagick library?

Tags: node.js, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I am attempting to convert pdf files into a preview icon jpg
using the imagemagick library for NodeJS. I am trying to 
generate a preview of only the **first page** (for multi-page pdfs).

In the normal command line imagemagick program this can be 
done easily by saying **"convert file.pdf[0] file.jpg"**
where the [0] tells it to only convert the first page.

However I am not sure how to do that with this library.
I tried concatenating [0] to the filename, but it just 
reads it as part of the real file name.  Anyone know of 
a way around this using this library?

I had a look around for a while and found this, but 
they are not using this library. 
[Convert PDF to PNG Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903737/convert-pdf-to-png-node-js)

The specific library I am using is located here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

The code I am working with is below:

```
            let path = '/tmp/';
            let pageNumber = '[0]';
            let filePath =  path + fileId + fileName + pageNumber; 
            let imgFilePath = path + fileId + '.jpg';
            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
            writeStream.on('error',err => {
              reject(err);
            });
            stream.pipe(writeStream);


              im.convert([
                filePath,
                '-background','white',
                '-alpha','remove',
                '-resize','192x192',
                '-quality','100',
                imgFilePath
              ],
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are concatenating the **[0]** part onto the filename before you do the conversion.  You should concatenate the **[0]** within the scope of the convert function like this:

```
            let path = '/tmp/';
            let filePath =  path + fileId + fileName;
            let imgFilePath = path + fileId + '.jpg';
            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
            writeStream.on('error',err => {
              reject(err);
            });
            stream.pipe(writeStream);


              im.convert([
                filePath + '[0]',
                '-background','white',
                '-alpha','remove',
                '-resize','192x192',
                '-quality','100',
                imgFilePath
              ],
```

This solution is tested working.